# How to generate the vocab with the given seperator in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a task and I wish to use TextCNN to finish it. The input sequence is like this:

```
"1|100 2|101 3|200 ..."
```

I wish to split the sequence with space and get the vocab like `{'1|100': 1, '2|101': 2, '3|200':3, ...}`. I tried to use `tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor` to generate the vocab and transform the sequence, however it treated the symbol '|' as seperator too and returned `{'1': 1, '100': 2, '2': 3, '101': 4, '3': 5, '200':6, ...}`

So how can I generate the vocab with the seperator that I chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with tf [tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) customizing the `filters` argument

```
text = ['1|100 2|101 3|200', '1|100 2|111 3|210']

tk = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(filters='')
tk.fit_on_texts(text)

tk.word_index
# {'1|100': 1, '2|101': 2, '3|200': 3, '2|111': 4, '3|210': 5}
```